# Join permutations with newline fails

Tags: python

From

```
from itertools import permutations
perms = ['\n'.join(p) for p in permutations(['mac', 'hi', 'ne'])]
print(set(perms))
```

I get

```
{'hi\nne\nmac', 'hi\nmac\nne', 'ne\nmac\nhi', 'mac\nhi\nne', 'ne\nhi\nmac', 'mac\nne\nhi'}
```

And if I try

```
from itertools import permutations
perms = [''.join(p) for p in permutations(['mac', 'hi', 'ne'])]
print(set(perms), sep='\n')
```

I get

```
{'macnehi', 'nehimac', 'nemachi', 'machine', 'hinemac', 'himacne'}
```

My desired output should look like

```
macnehi
nehimac
nemachi
machine
hinemac
himacne
```

I don't know what I'm messing. I'm appreciate any hints.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Expand the set:

```
print(*set(perms), sep='\n')
```

Or, join it explicitly:

```
print('\n'.join(set(perms)))
```

Comment: It works, Thank you very much! In 9 Minutes I can accept your answer.

Comment: Is one of the code preferable?

Comment: I'd prefer the first one. It's less explicit, but should use less memory

Comment: @JohnGoofy your desired output in the questions is not what this code will output